# Message saved in model isn't displaying on the view

Tags: grails, groovy

Message saved to model not displaying on view.

My controller class is as follows:

```
@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')
def verify( Long id){
    def model = [:]
    if(User.get(id)!=null){

        model['user']=(User.get(id)).name
        redirect( action : "newPage", model: model)

    }
}
```

In my view i just typed the following:

```
<html><head></head><body>${user}${user}${user}</body></html>
```

But this value is null, and it doesn't get printed. Can someone help me here please.

UPDATE

```
@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')
    def newPage(){}
```

UPDATE 2

```
@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')
def verify( Long id){
   def model = [:]
model['user']=(User.get(id)).name
   redirect( action : "newPage", params: model)

}
```

It gives NULL when i print `params.user`

```
def newPage(){
println params.user
    render view: 'newPage', model: [user: params.user]
}
```

Comment: Does the new action you redirect to pass the user to the model?  Also are you sure the name is not null?

Comment: I included a println and printed `model['user']` and it was displayed. What do you mean by `Does the new action you redirect to pass the user to the model?`

Comment: Well you are redirecting to the 'newPage' action -- what does that action do with the model?  Did you mean to `render` instead?

Comment: I have added the code above. It does nothing for now. But, i thought i can directly refer to the model from the view

Comment: You can, but you have to pass it to the view.  Currently you are not passing it to anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the action you are redirecting to, you need to [render](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Controllers/render.html) the data:

```
def newPage(){
    render view: 'newPage', model: [user: params.user]
}
```

Furthermore, you need to pass that data via the `params`, not through the model (since the [model is not present](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Controllers/redirect.html) for redirecting):

```
@Secured('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')
def verify( Long id){
   //...
   redirect( action : "newPage", params: model)
```

Comment: How should i refer it from the view if so ?